# URL returns NIL if UID is added to storage path. But Image stored in database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Here is my code, It looks perfect, but when I try to add UID (to make the path unique) and then save the image and get download URL, download image doesnt get generated but the image get saved. How to fix this?

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
       
if let fbProfilePicture = profilePic?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4) {
        
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images")
       
    let data = Data()
        
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
              
    print(userID)

    var profileRef = storageRef.child(userID)
       
    let riversRef = storageRef.child("profile.png")
       
    let uploadTask = riversRef.putData(fbProfilePicture, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        guard let metadata = metadata else {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }
    
    print("Entered")
           
    riversRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in     
        print(url)
            
        self.db.collection("customUser").document(userID).setData(["Name": self.userName, "password": self.password, "Email": self.email, "DateCreated": formattedDate, "imageURL": url?.absoluteString])
            
        guard let downloadURL = url else {
           // Uh-oh, an error occurred!            
           return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `riversRef` to both `putData` and `downloadURL`, although this storage reference is currently pointing to the child referenced by `profile.png`. Looking at you're code, you should be using `profileRef` instead (and appending the filetype e.g. `.png`).

So your code would look like:

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
       
if let fbProfilePicture = profilePic?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4) {
        
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images")
       
    let data = Data()
        
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
              
    print(userID)

    let filename = userID + ".png"
    
    var profileRef = storageRef.child(filename)
       
    let uploadTask = profileRef.putData(fbProfilePicture, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        guard let metadata = metadata else {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }
    
    print("Entered")
           
    profileRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in     
        print(url)
            
        self.db.collection("customUser").document(userID).setData(["Name": self.userName, "password": self.password, "Email": self.email, "DateCreated": formattedDate, "imageURL": url?.absoluteString])
            
        guard let downloadURL = url else {
           // Uh-oh, an error occurred!            
           return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried the code you have modified, 

But still getting the same error, download URL returns value as nil. 

It works perfect if I don't add UID anywhere in database as reference. Kind of weird error, The URL gets generated and the file can be found on firebase, but it returns nil when UID is associated anywhere.

Comment: @Vjme what type is `Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid`? If you `print(filename)` what is shown in the console?

Comment: The User ID getting generated and I have printed to ensure it, The path creates with the particular UID and image stored inside it, The problem is no URL is printed it just says nil

And when printing file name it shows this "6CWCj2hAeHdwer345AxGRUND3t2.png"

Comment: If I remove UID from all the place and make sure it doesn't used anywhere to store the image, Then I am getting value from download url , it prints the exact file URL .

Comment: @Vjme what if you change `let filename = userID + ".png"` to `let filename = UUID().uuidString + ".png"`. I can't see anything in Firebase docs that restrict filenames.

Comment: Have tried with above changes, still getting Nil as value returned. Thanks for trying to help, But breaking my head from morning, it looks weird, that it runs well if we dont add UID to location reference or file name. :-/